# binaryjs - nodejs mp3 audio stream and play back

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, streaming

i want to Stream a .mp3 file from a Client to a Server, both are using NodeJS.
i'm using [binaryjs](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs) to stream the file.

*client:*

```
var BinaryClient = require('binaryjs').BinaryClient;
var fs = require('fs');

var client = BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
    client.on('open', function(stream){

       client.send(fs.createReadStream('music.mp3'), {
           name : 'music'
       });
});
```

*server:*

```
var BinaryServer    = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000});
    server.on('connection', function(client){

        client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){

            var data = [];
            stream.on('data', function(chunk){
                console.log('Recieve Chunk: ' + data.length);
                data.push(chunk);
            });

            stream.on('end', function() {
                console.log('complete data' + data);
            });
        });
    });
```

i got my binary data stream and want them to
work with something like [player.js](https://github.com/turingou/player) 
to get a direct audio output with nodejs.

but i don`t know how to get the binary data into a usable stream file
that works with solution like [player.js](https://github.com/turingou/player).

hope somebody can help me to get a working solution.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone who has similar problems to solve:

1. Try to create a new BlobFile from the data array immediately when gathering the data and not at the end
2. read the Blob as an ArrayBuffer
3. decode Audio Data
4. play them

here is a snippet:

```
   ....

   var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
   var fileReader = new FileReader();
   var source = null;
   var audioBuffer = null;

   var data = [];
        stream.on('data', function(chunk){
            console.log('Recieve Chunk: ' + data.length);
            data.push(chunk);
            var blob = new Blob(streamData);
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
            context.decodeAudioData(buf, function(buffer) {
                 audioBuffer = null;
                 audioBuffer = buffer;
                 source = context.createBufferSource();
                 source.buffer = audioBuffer;
                 source.connect(context.destination);
                 source.start()
        });


    ....
```

not tested and propably not working, but I hope it will help some of you guys

Comment: before executing decodeAudioData you have to wait until the Buffer is full with fileReader.onloadend